duende missing claims
I'm testing Duende Identity Server.
I used the sample named 6_JS_with_backend to test Google IDP. The initial sample is working fine.
I modified it to replace the in memory data by a database (using Identity Framework) and then the claims are missing the profile information (name, givenname, familyname). As soon as I switch back to "In Memory" it's working fine again.
The database has been created succesfully by EF migration and there are no execution errors.
I don't understand what's happening.
Javascript client is not modified.
IdentityServer ConfigureServices:
 public static WebApplication ConfigureServices(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
 {
 var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name;

 builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
 string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
 builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

 builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

 builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
 {
     options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
 })
     .AddConfigurationStoreCache()
     .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
     {
         options.EnablePooling = true;
         options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
         {
             builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, configure =>
             {
                 configure.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly);
             });
         };
     })
     .AddOperationalStore(options =>
     {
         options.EnablePooling = true;
         options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
         {
             builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, configure =>
             {
                 configure.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly);
             });
         };

         options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
         options.TokenCleanupInterval = (int)TimeSpan.FromDays(20).TotalSeconds;
     });
 builder.Services.AddIdentityServerConfiguration(opt => opt.LicenseKey = "<TEST>").AddClientConfigurationStore();
 builder.Services.AddConfigurationDbContext<ConfigurationDbContext>(options =>
 {
     options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
 });

 var configuration = builder.Configuration;
 // Put in Keyvault
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
     .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
     {
         options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
         options.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"]!;
         options.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"]!;
     });      

 return builder.Build();

}
ApplicationRoles:


    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace IdentityServer.Models
{
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        
    }
}



ApplicationUser


using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace IdentityServer.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string? TenantId { get; set; }
        public string? License { get; set; }
    }
}



In Memory result:

With database result:

I checked in the database.
The client is here, clientscopes and identityresources as well.


I found out that there are no userclaims in Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.IdentityResource named profile. And the table named IdentityResourceClaims is empty. I didn't find any doc about this and the code sample that provisions the table doesn't fill this table.
I filled the IdentityResourceClaims and it solved the issue.
